# Use cmake to generate Visual Studio sln project without link to original CMakeFiles.txt

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake

I need to use cmake to generate visual studio sln file, BUT I want to ensure, that this generated *.sln file will not be connected with original CMakeFiles.txt (I want to generate sln file once).

I know that this is not typical usage and the connection with source CMakeFiles.txt is in standard usage perfect, but in my case it is not wanted -- I want to distribute these sln files (solution with projects) to some colleagues, who do not have CMake.

Maybe there is another approach (except cmake), to create few visual studio project without annoying clicking in Visual Studio.

Thanks,

Radek

Comment: There is a command to get it to stop regeneration while in the IDE. I am looking for that in my code.

Comment: Here it is: ***option (CMAKE_SUPPRESS_REGENERATION  "Suppress the cmake macro that causes regeneration of build scripts during build" ON)***

Comment: From first quick tests, it seems it is working. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to use cmake to generate visual studio sln file, BUT I want to
>   ensure, that this generated *.sln file will not be connected with
>   original CMakeFiles.txt

By design CMake will generate solution files that depend on CMake so this part is not really possible with CMake alone.

> Maybe there is another approach (except cmake), to create few visual
>   studio project without annoying clicking in Visual Studio.

There is a way to stop regeneration in the IDE. I use this in many of my projects most likely for the same reason you do. At least with older versions of Visual Studio the regeneration caused dozens of prompts. Although I believe Visual Studio 2013 only prompts 1 time now I still enable this. The following code (inserted near the top of my root CMakelists.txt) is what I use to enable the option to suppress IDE regeneration.

```
option (CMAKE_SUPPRESS_REGENERATION "Suppress the cmake macro that causes regeneration of build scripts during build" ON)
```